# Что предпочесть - EntityManager vs Session

Tags: hibernate, jpa

В каких случаях для работы с базой не обойтись без `Hibernate` интерфейса `Session`.

Верно ли утверждение, что к `Session API` следует прибегать (собственно, невозможно не прибегнуть) в том случае, когда вы строите запросы на основе `HQL | JPQL`, либо `Criteria API`? И это, пожалуй, единственная причина.

Кажется, в 90% случаев так и поступают.

Но `EntityManager API` содержит и сами методы `createQuery`, `createNativeQuery`, `createNamedQuery` - почему бы не пользоваться методами этого интерфейса?

И в чем разница между `Session` в `JPA` и в `Hibernate`?

Answer (score 7):

Существуют т.н. `Container Managed Transactions (CMT)`, т.е., транзакции, управляемые контейнером.

Контейнер - это окружение, в котором работает ваше приложение, например - сервер приложений. При использовании `CMT` ваш софт не управляет началом/завершением транзакций, вместо этого контейнер сам решает когда начинать транзакции, и когда их завершать.

Таким образом, в исходном коде у вас нет строк `transaction.begin()/transaction.commit().`

**При работе с `CMT` обычно используется `EntityManager`**. Обычно, `EntityManager` передаётся в ваше приложение контейнером с использованием **`Dependency Injection (DI)`**.

Существуют `Bean Managed Transactions (BMT)`. Представляют собой то же самое, что и `CMT`, но с одним отличием - вы в коде явно управляете транзакциями, а не доверяете это контейнеру. Здесь также применяются `EntityManager` и `DI`.

Существует еще один подход - вы не используете `DI`, вместо этого в вашем приложении реализован код, самостоятельно осуществляющий доступ к источнику данных. В таких приложениях обычно работа осуществляется через `Session`.

Я описал общий случай, нередко бывают и отличные от него - частные случаи. Например, вам требуется получить доступ к специфическим функциям `Session` в приложении, использующем `CMT`. Бывают также случаи, когда `DI` не работает: обычно это бывает, когда вам требуется получить доступ к источнику данных из потока, созданного не контейнером, а вашим приложением.

Возможности, доступные из `Session` и из `EntityManager` - одинаковы на 99%. Решение, **что использовать - скорее архитектурное, чем функциональное.**